# Wald's equation, upperbound

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

I have a random variable $Y$ which is the summation of randomly many other random variables. i.e. $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{t} X_i$. I know $E[t]=\tau$ and for each $i$, $E[X_i]$ has a different value but there is a $b$ such that for all $i$, $E[X_i]\leq b$. Can we conclude that $E[Y]\leq \tau b$. The other conditions of Wald Equation hold.

Comment: Are $X_i,t$ independent?

Comment: Yes. All the other conditions of Wald hold

Comment: So, to my mind it should work : $\mathbb E[Y] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y|t]]$, and since $t$ is discrete, it is enough to find $\mathbb E[Y | t=k] = \mathbb E[ \sum_{i=1}^k X_i | t=k ] = \mathbb E[ \sum_{i=1}^k X_i ] \le \mathbb E[ \sum_{i=1}^k b] = kb$ (we can forget about condition due to independece). So we actually get $ \mathbb E[Y|t] \le tb$. And since $\mathbb E[A] \le \mathbb E[B]$ for $A \le B$, we get $\mathbb E[Y] = \mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y|t]] \le \mathbb E[tb] = \tau \cdot b$

Comment: You cannot take expectation inside the sum if we don't have Wald's identity

Comment: Due to use of conditional expectation, our sum is finite and not random (at that moment), so we can use linearity of expectation